# How to redirect from the www to the non-www version in an HTACCESS file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I have installed the Laravel 5.2 in my Linux Server And I made it so hardly by modifying the HTACCESS file , So now I'm trying to make a redirection from the www to the non-www version I mean like stackoverflow from www.example.com >>TO>> example.com , But I'm afraid because I may crash my server so please help with the explanation of the code please :

```
RewriteEngine on 

# I changed my website real name to example
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example/index.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `/example/` directory? What is full URL to access your Laravel home page?

Comment: yes "example" is a directory because the Laravel Project have to be hidden from the public access , this is what I've been told to do in the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# I changed my website real name to example
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^/?$ example/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(?!example/)(.*)$ example/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not answering you until now :) , It's working but there is a problem when I go to `www.example.com/ex1/ex2/ex3.php` it redirects me to `example.com/index.php` , but I want it to redirect me to `example.com/ex1/ex2/ex3.php` , I mean I want to keep the parameters , and sorry for bothering you ^__^

Comment: Completely clear your browser cache while testing this. Do you have any other rule or any other .htaccess?